# How to use the created asset as Free Balance

Tags: assets

I want to create a new Asset names PET in Substrate. What I did is from the PolkadotJS App Created and Minted the asset using the account Alice
I want to make this assetid to use as Freee Balance and make it default
How to accomplish that using Substrate

Comment: This question may be helpful for you: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/711/when-should-i-use-balances-pallet-and-when-should-i-use-assets-pallet

Answer (score 2):

As per the [linked answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/711/when-should-i-use-balances-pallet-and-when-should-i-use-assets-pallet) from Bruno, an asset is not the same as a native currency so at this point is not used for payments.

In your own chain you can however name the native currency anything you want and change the decimals/supply, etc.