# Does DOT and KSM have Currency AssetId?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, balances, assets

I believed that Substrate-based tokens have its own assetId
Question is, does relay chain tokens like "DOT" and "KSM" have their assetId too?
I tried to find out where it is implemented through parity-tech/polkadot github code, I can't find it...

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [previous answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/711/when-should-i-use-balances-pallet-and-when-should-i-use-assets-pallet) that details the differences between `assets` and `balances`.

At this point a currency is not the same as an asset, so doesn't have an assetid inside the assets environment.