# Custom emitting, minting, and max total supply

Tags: token

We would like to implement custom emitting of the native token, like 1 token per block. Can you point us where the minting happens using substrate? Which pallet implements it?

Also is there a way to implement max total supply of the native token?

Answer (score 2):

For minting logic in Substrate you can use the `fungible` trait:

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungible

For example, you could use `mint_into` trait to mint:

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungible/trait.Mutate.html#method.mint_into

> Note: There is also the [`Currency`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/currency/index.html) trait but that is being deprecated in favor of the [`fungible`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungible) trait.

Pallet-wise you can use pallet-balances - it is designed to store and manage your native currency.

Pallet balances sets the total issuance of your native currency in its `GenesisBuild` by adding up the amount that each "genesis" account has:

```rust
let total = self.balances.iter().fold(Zero::zero(), |acc: T::Balance, &(_, n)| acc + n);

<TotalIssuance<T, I>>::put(total);
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/aeb8c3107f79afef081dde2b9aa2866a6596f6ba/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L468-L470

These accounts can be endowed in the `GenesisConfig`.

For example in the Substrate node-template, you will see the following in the chain spec:

```rust
balances: BalancesConfig {
    // Configure endowed accounts with initial balance of 1 << 60.
    balances: endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|k| (k, 1 << 60)).collect(),
},
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/aeb8c3107f79afef081dde2b9aa2866a6596f6ba/bin/node-template/node/src/chain_spec.rs#LL140C1-L143C5

If you spin up the node-template and check the `totalIssuance`, you will see the following:

[image]

For the development config there are four accounts:

```rust
// Pre-funded accounts
vec![
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
],
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/aeb8c3107f79afef081dde2b9aa2866a6596f6ba/bin/node-template/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L55-L60

`1 << 60` is equivalent to 1,152,921,504,606,846,976

So pallet balance's total issuance will be 1,152,921,504,606,846,976 * 4 == 4,611,686,018,427,387,904 which is what you see in the attached screenshot.

Keep in mind `totalIssuance` can change, but it is up to you to define the logic when to change `totalIssuance`. You can simply not have any logic that will increment `totalIssuance` - hence giving it a "soft" cap.

Related post:

- [How does a Substrate chain set the max total supply?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/how-does-a-substrate-chain-set-the-max-total-supply)
- [When should I use Balances Pallet and when should I use Assets Pallet?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/711/when-should-i-use-balances-pallet-and-when-should-i-use-assets-pallet/712#712)

For doing something every block, you can use Substrate's `on_initialize` hook:

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/trait.Hooks.html#method.on_initialize